# PinchGestureRecognizer in .NET MAUI doesnt stay inside its container

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I have a png image which i have to zoom (in and out). Every time I zoom in on the image, the image pre-zooms as desired, but the frame it is in expands across the entire application. On the left side there is a locked shell flyout menu (will be set to flyout later). When the image is zoomed in, it should of course stay in its frame and this should not change. Only a zoom in should be realized.

xaml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 Shell.BackgroundColor="#696969"
                 xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
                 x:Class="EngineCheck.Views.EngineView"
                 xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:EngineCheck.ViewModels">
        <!--Engine image view-->
        <Frame x:Name="scaledContentContainer" MaximumHeightRequest="1000" 
            MaximumWidthRequest="1000">
            <Image x:Name="image" 
                   Aspect="AspectFit" 
                   Source="korm110dk1_dwt000280_20230626145746_w3b6rm0110_04_01_io.png">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <PinchGestureRecognizer PinchUpdated="OnPinchUpdated" />
                    <PanGestureRecognizer PanUpdated="OnPanUpdated"/>
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
           </Image>
        </Frame>
    </ContentPage>
```

xaml.cs file

```
public partial class EngineView:ContentPage {
    private double _currentScale = 1;
    private double _startScale = 1;
    private double _xOffset = 0;
    private double _yOffset = 0;
    EngineViewModel vm = new();
    readonly Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public EngineView() {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = vm;
    }

    private void OnPinchUpdated(object sender, PinchGestureUpdatedEventArgs e) {
        try {
            switch(e.Status) {
                case GestureStatus.Started:
                    _startScale = Content.Scale;
                    Content.AnchorX = 0;
                    Content.AnchorY = 0;
                    break;
                case GestureStatus.Running: {
                        _currentScale += (e.Scale - 1) * _startScale;
                        _currentScale = Math.Max(1, _currentScale);
                        _currentScale = Math.Min(4, _currentScale);
                        var renderedX = Content.X + _xOffset;
                        var deltaX = renderedX / Width;
                        var deltaWidth = Width / (Content.Width * _startScale);
                        var originX = (e.ScaleOrigin.X - deltaX) * deltaWidth;
                        var renderedY = Content.Y + _yOffset;
                        var deltaY = renderedY / Height;
                        var deltaHeight = Height / (Content.Height * _startScale);
                        var originY = (e.ScaleOrigin.Y - deltaY) * deltaHeight;
                        var targetX = _xOffset - (originX * Content.Width) *                 
                            (_currentScale - _startScale);
                        var targetY = _yOffset - (originY * Content.Height) * 
                            (_currentScale - _startScale);
                        Content.TranslationX = Math.Min(0, Math.Max(targetX, -    
                            Content.Width * (_currentScale - 1)));
                            Content.TranslationY = Math.Min(0, Math.Max(targetY, -     
                            Content.Height * (_currentScale - 1)));
                        Content.Scale = _currentScale;
                        break;
                    }
                case GestureStatus.Completed:
                    _xOffset = Content.TranslationX;
                    _yOffset = Content.TranslationY;
                    break;
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            logger.Error(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void OnPanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e) {
        try {
            if(Content.Scale == 1) {
                return;
            }
            switch(e.StatusType) {
                case GestureStatus.Running:
                    var newX = (e.TotalX * Scale) + _xOffset;
                    var newY = (e.TotalY * Scale) + _yOffset;
                    var width = (Content.Width * Content.Scale);
                    var height = (Content.Height * Content.Scale);
                    var canMoveX = width > Application.Current.MainPage.Width;
                    var canMoveY = height > Application.Current.MainPage.Height;
                    if(canMoveX) {
                        var minX = (width - (Application.Current.MainPage.Width / 2)) * 
                        -1;
                        var maxX = Math.Min(Application.Current.MainPage.Width / 2, 
                            width / 2);
                        if(newX < minX) {
                            newX = minX;
                        }
                        if(newX > maxX) {
                            newX = maxX;
                        }
                    } else {
                        newX = 0;
                    }
                    if(canMoveY) {
                        var minY = (height - (Application.Current.MainPage.Height / 2)) 
                            * -1;
                        var maxY = Math.Min(Application.Current.MainPage.Width / 2, 
                            height / 2);
                        if(newY < minY) {
                            newY = minY;
                        }
                        if(newY > maxY) {
                            newY = maxY;
                        }
                    } else {
                        newY = 0;
                    }
                    Content.TranslationX = newX;
                    Content.TranslationY = newY;
                    break;
                case GestureStatus.Completed:
                    _xOffset = Content.TranslationX;
                    _yOffset = Content.TranslationY;
                    break;
                case GestureStatus.Started:
                    break;
                case GestureStatus.Canceled:
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            logger.Error(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I have already tried it with different containers. Frame, ScrollView, Stacklayout, etc but everywhere the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every time I zoom in on the image, the image pre-zooms as desired, but the frame it is in expands across the entire application. On the left side there is a locked shell flyout menu (will be set to flyout later).

Replacing all "Content" of `OnPinchUpdated` and `OnPanUpdated` to "image"(value of `x:Name` of your `Image` control) can fix your problem.

"Content" is property of ContentPage, that is to say you are zooming in and out the whole page instead of the image.